# Access the value of the cancel button on a dialog prompt in shiny mobile

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I need to know how to access to the value of the cancel button on a dialog prompt in shiny mobile.

Here's an example of the app

```
library(shinyMobile)

ui <- f7Page(
  title = "myApp",
  f7SingleLayout(
    navbar = '',
    f7Card(
      title = 'card1',
      f7Button(inputId = "go", label = "go")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    f7Dialog(
      title = "write",
      inputId = "someText",
      type = "prompt",
      text = "write something",
      session = session
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$someText, {
    f7Dialog(
      title = "you write",
      text = paste("you write this text: ", input$someText, sep = ""),
      session = session
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see, when I push the "Ok" button on the dialog prompt, I can trigger another event. However, I want to fully refresh the app when pushing the "cancel" button on the first dialog but I don't know how to access to the value in the input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example of the app.

Comment: Just edited the post.